# What does the write limitation on ancestor queries mean?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

According to the documentation, when using [ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor) the following limitation will be enforced:

> Ancestor queries allow you to make strongly consistent queries to the
>   datastore, however entities with the same ancestor are limited to 1
>   write per second.

```
class Customer(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Purchase(ndb.Model):
    price = ndb.IntegerProperty

purchase1 = Purchase(ancestor=customer_entity.key)
purchase2 = Purchase(ancestor=customer_entity.key)
purchase3 = Purchase(ancestor=customer_entity.key)

purchase1.put()
purchase2.put()
purchase3.put()
```

Taking the same example, if I was about to write three purchases at same time, would I get an exception, as its less than a second apart?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find two excellent videos about the datastore, strong consistency and entity groups. [Datastore Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQazhzcC-rg) and [Datastore Query, Index and Transaction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4CiMWy0J70).

About your example. You can use a `put_multi()` which "counts" for a single entity group write.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of `put_multi`. It was just hypothetical, if several `put()` came through in the web app for the same entity group, how would gae react. Will it throw an exception or put the request in a queue to be executed within 3 seconds? Thanks for the videos. I'll watch them

Comment: see this question for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454467/google-app-engine-hrd-what-if-i-exceed-the-1-write-per-second-limit-for-writin

Comment: If you use the update in a transaction you can retry using transaction options.

Comment: Thanks for the videos and link. I watched them, it was helpful. In my example above `Customer` and `Purchase` are within the same entity group, correct? Does it mean I can update either of those two only once per second?

Comment: That's correct. Usually the contention limit only comes into play when you have several requests trying to write to the same entity group at the same time. The datastore doesn't impose an artificial 1 write/second limitation. This is a best practices recommendation for avoiding write performance and contention issues. If every once in a while you write 2 entities in a group at the same time, you'll be ok.